# How to use geth attach and port numbers?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am attempting to connect using two nodes on separate machines:

```
geth attach
```

I enter this in machine 2-

```
geth attach http://10.132.0.2:8501
```

and get this -

```
Fatal: Failed to start the JavaScript console: api modules: 
Post http://10.132.0.2:8501: dial tcp 10.132.0.2:8501: getsockopt: connection refused
```

I am not that clear on how the nodes connect either using UDP or TCP; or if http is used.

How can I debug this? Should we be using enode anyway?

The node is running on machine 1.

**From machine 1 hosting the node**

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8501          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8502          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.132.0.2:22           92.238.41.13:49637      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    316 10.132.0.2:22           92.238.41.13:50681      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.132.0.2:51968        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.132.0.2:51944        169.254.169.254:80      CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        0      0 10.132.0.2:22           92.238.41.13:50671      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.132.0.2:22           92.238.41.13:50036      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.132.0.2:51978        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54108         127.0.0.1:30311         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.132.0.2:51962        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.132.0.2:22           92.238.41.13:49959      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::30311                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::30312                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:30311         127.0.0.1:54108         ESTABLISHED
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 10.132.0.2:123          0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 :::30310                :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::30311                :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::30312                :::*                               
udp6       0      0 fe80::4001:aff:fe84:123 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*
```

**from geth on machine 1 (running node)**

> > admin.nodeInfo {   enode: "enode://d889d565b3ddc37491d131aed1c23d0a7b30a185bb925f325c7830b2ae710bc127010487f39f32d889afd1284ea31aa893adddda2197f2763485926970620381@[::]:30312",
> >     id:
> >     "d889d565b3ddc37491d131aed1c23d0a7b30a185bb925f325c7830b2ae710bc127010487f39f32d889afd1284ea31aa893adddda2197f2763485926970620381",
> >     ip: "::",   listenAddr: "[::]:30312",   name:
> >     "Geth/v1.8.2-stable-b8b9f7f4/linux-amd64/go1.9.4",   ports: {
> >         discovery: 30312,
> >         listener: 30312   },   protocols: {
> >         eth: {
> >           config: {
> >             byzantiumBlock: 4,
> >             chainId: 1515,
> >             clique: {...},
> >             eip150Block: 2,
> >             eip150Hash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
> >             eip155Block: 3,
> >             eip158Block: 3,
> >             homesteadBlock: 1
> >           },
> >           difficulty: 27923,
> >           genesis: "0x702d8ca9647d171a6596a775888f71c7c0f3ddb011fbffcb921be685b2ef33b7",
> >           head: "0xa9e2d5d7e55653b9a0b47ddfa0650105a9d0e5487b6cff207d191d33cdefa830",
> >           network: 1515

Here is the connection
  string for node1 -

> nohup geth --datadir node1/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30311 --rpc
>   --rpcaddr 'loca lhost' --rpcport 8501 --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner' --bootnod es
>   'enode://601ade737b81f16abdd0ce9983b63eb12050c4ef89c46b8fdbf3e3e6c951cc02dffe
>   36f87200033107cf8b007355e780fba16b67d1d46603b1321f07314ea46b@127.0.0.1:30310'
>   -- networkid 1515 --gasprice '1' -unlock 'fcad53c780a4f6c66b3daca331fe72fc6559c367'  --password
>   node1/pwdnode1.txt --mine &

Comment: To launch your geth, did you use --rpcport 8501 ?

Comment: I just added the conn string, I think my mistake is rpcaddr?

Comment: But if I just use geth attach what is the default? Is that IPC? What confuses me is what protocols are used and when, we have UDP, TCP, IPC, Http, and RPC. Has someone a link about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RPC listening address is 127.0.0.1, which can only be connected from the same host.

If you need to connect from across networks, try
`--rpcaddr 10.132.0.2`

Comment: should connected node's port be set publicly accessable?

Comment: should connected node's port be set publicly accessable? I am getting following error: `Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen tcp IP:PORT: bind: cannot assign requested address`

Comment: @alper Best to ask as a separate question

Comment: Isn't only valid IP addresses are `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0` for the `--rpcaddr`?